# Swift how to use pin code to access keychain

Tags: swift, authentication, touch

Here is my code for the touchId function. I would like it to resort to having the user enter the pin code they use to unlock their phone in order to verify their identity and login without typing in the username and password.  But I only want them to have this option when touch ID isn't working or is unavailable.

How would I go about doing so?

```
 @IBAction func touchIDLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    let authenticationContext = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    //check if device supports touch id, if not show error and stop
    guard authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) else{
        displayAlert("TOUCH ID ERROR", msg: "This device does not support TouchID", option: false)
        return
    }

    authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Verify who you are to login", reply: {[unowned self](success, error) -> Void in
        if(success){

            //Fingerprint recognized
            var stored_pass = ""
            var stored_user = ""
            stored_pass = (self.my_keychain_wrapper.myObjectForKey("v_Data") as? String)!
            stored_user = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("username") as? String)!
            if(!stored_pass.isEmpty || !stored_user.isEmpty){
                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(stored_user, password: stored_pass, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

                    //unsuccessful login display error message
                    if user == nil {
                        if let error_string = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String{
                            self.displayAlert("ERROR IN LOGIN", msg: error_string, option: false)
                        }
                    }

                    //successful login
                    else{
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dashboard_segue", sender: self)
                    }
                })
            }
            else{
                self.displayAlert("LOGIN ERROR", msg: "No valid login credentials were found", option: false)
            }
        }

            //error check
        else{
            if let error = error{
                let message = self.errorMessageForLAErrorCode(error.code)
                self.displayAlert("TOUCH ID ERROR", msg: message, option: false)
            }
        }
        })
}
```

Comment: I think you need to manage your own pin and use it as a fallback of Touch ID fails

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lapolicy/1514164-deviceownerauthentication

Comment: That's kind of helpful but I still don't know how to make use of that :/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, iOS does not provide a means to verify an entry against the system passcode.

If touchID should fail, the app may need to manage its own password. [This library](https://github.com/yankodimitrov/SwiftPasscodeLock) allows an app to manage a passcode with a UI much like the system UI, and you could encourage users to set the app passcode to that of the system.